# Using the same event name in different contracts

Tags: solidity, web3js, events, filters

Suppose I have two different contracts, and I implement an event in each one of them.

If I use the same event name in both contracts, will it make it more difficult (or even impossible) to filter the events of a specific contract?

Should I (or would I be better off) using a unique name for each event?

For all it matters, I am using web3.js from the client side.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If the two contracts don't inherit from each other and are deployed as separate contracts at separate addresses, it should not be a problem.

Comment: Thank you. What if a function in contract A calls a function in contract B? On the client side, the receipt logs appear to contain both events. If they have the same name, then the method that I use for reading a specific event becomes "pretty ugly", since it needs to rely on the order in which the events were emitted. At least that's the case in web3.js, when I parse the transaction receipt. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think you should open a new question which includes the code you are using to get events